# Where is the error in this Discord Bot who givea roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the Code:

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!verify"):
        await message.author.send("Du wurdest Verifiziert")
        await client.add_roles(message.author, "721417651074891786")


client.run('Token')```
````

and Thats the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Discord.py", line 20, in on_message
    await client.add_roles(message.author, "721417651074891786")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

I have no ideas whats wrong with the code.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you might be referring to some old documentation or tutorials.

In rewrite (v1.x) adding roles, among other things, has changed - see the references - and here would be the code written for your case:

```py
role = message.guild.get_role(721417651074891786) # IDs are now ints
await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Before continuing, I'd highly recommend reading through the links below (and perhaps also finding more recent tutorials) to make sure you know when you're looking at rewrite code as opposed to async (v0.16.x) code and familiarising yourself with the changes.

---

**References:**

- [Major changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#) - Notably in your case, [snowflakes (ids) are now ints](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int), and [models are now stateful](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful) (basically not everything is a method of the client class anymore).
- [`Guild.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)